# XML node in Windows Phone

Tags: c#-4.0, windows-phone-8, xmlnode

how do I enable XmlNode in windows phone 8,
I am using windows phone 8, and I also added

```
using system.xml;
using system.xml.linq;
```

but not getting some xmlnode and etc.

can anyone help me?

Comment: Use `XNode` instead of `XmlNode`. [Have you tried?](https://www.google.com/#q=xmlnode+windows+phone)

Comment: @Romasz ok..I ahve not tried yet..thank you